# Add dynamic HTML from JavaScript in Angular 2/4/5 and bind events

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I am trying to add new HTML code via AJAX to an Angular 5 app and add click event to the elements. But the click event doesn't work as expected, I can't use the 2 way data-binding way because I am using the jQuery data-tables plugins and he add the HTML to the Dom and not the angular template.

I have tried:

```js
<button  (click)='myClassFunction()'>Click!</button>  this line does nothing
<button  onclick='myClassFunction()'>Click!</button>  this line said myClassFunction is undefined
<button  onclick='this.myClassFunction()'>Click!</button> this line said myClassFunction is undefined
```

How can I bind this click event to my function?

Comment: Please use (click) instead of onClick in Angular

Comment: for angular i think its on-click

Comment: i tryied (click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is written in **Typescript**.

When you serve or build your application, this typescript application is then **compiled, minified and uglified to native Javascript**.

This means that your

```
(click)="myClassFunction()"
```

Will become something along the lines of

```
onclick="srgu.gferu()"
```

And as you can see, Angular won't recognize that.

It doesn't matter if you use JQuery or plugins : **that is the way Angular works**.

To do that, you will need to create **window functions**, or global functions.

```
myClassFunction() {
  // Create your window function, make it tslint compliant
  window['myWindowClassFunction'] = () => {
    // Your function's logic here
  };
}
```

Now, in your appended HTML, you need to write

```
<button  onclick='window.myWindowClassFunction()'>Click!</button>
```

Comment: unfortunately i had to do it with some jquery but your answer is correct we cant do it in angular ):

Comment: Well I just explained you how you can do it, so yes it's possible :D But great if you succeed ! (Using JQuery with Angular is an anti-pattern though)